# Upgrading of Apache 2.2.15 to Apache 2.2.29 on CentOS 6.6 64 bit

Tags: apache, pci-dss, pci-compliance

I need to upgrade Apache 2.2.15 to 2.2.19 on my CentOS machine.
I tried following commands.

```
yum update httpd
yum install httpd-2.2.29
```

But its saying that no package available.
And i also have httpd-2.2.29.tar.gz file so also tell me that how to compile and install this.
I need to fix this for PCI compliance as there is vulnerability in this Apache version and i cant move forward to apache 2.4 as this version is not compatible.

Please tell me a way to upgrade the Apache 2.2.15 to Apache 2.2.29 and also tell me that how can I compile and install httpd-2.2.29.tar.gz file.
Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Better to ask on serverfault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are updating httpd via yum, you probably have the fixes for the CVEs that are in 2.2.29.   Look at the changelog for your updates and compare that to what is in 2.2.29.  Since Redhat backports their patches, you may find that you are already upgraded.